# hitTest(_:options:) don't recognize nodes behind ARKit planes

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

I place an object on a wall, then try to recognize tap on it, but hit test returns 0 objects. When I change Z position of the object and place it a little bit closer to cam, it's recognized well, but this isn't a solution, because planes are always changing and it can cover the object in any moment. How can I made hitTest work correctly and recognize my nodes behind planes? Or, maybe, I use the wrong method?

```
fileprivate func addNode(atPoint point: CGPoint) {
    let hits = sceneView.hitTest(point, types: .existingPlaneUsingExtent)
    if hits.count > 0, let firstHit = hits.first, let originNode = originNode {
        let node = originNode.clone()
        sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
        node.position = SCNVector3Make(firstHit.worldTransform.columns.3.x, firstHit.worldTransform.columns.3.y, firstHit.worldTransform.columns.3.z)
        let resize = simd_float4x4(SCNMatrix4MakeScale(0.2, 0.2, 0.2))
        let rotation = simd_float4x4(SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(.pi / 2, -1, 0, 0))
        let transform = simd_mul(firstHit.worldTransform, resize)
        let finalTransform = simd_mul(transform, rotation)
        node.simdTransform = finalTransform
        addedNodes.insert(node)
    }
}

func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first else {
        print("Unable to identify touches on any plane. Ignoring interaction...")
        return
    }

    let touchPoint = touch.location(in: sceneView)

    let hits = sceneView.hitTest(touchPoint, options: [SCNHitTestOption.boundingBoxOnly: true])
    let filtered = hits.filter({ addedNodes.contains($0.node) })
    print("\(hits.count) vs \(filtered.count), \(hits.first?.node.name ?? "no name")")
    if let node = filtered.first?.node {
        node.removeFromParentNode()
        addedNodes.remove(node)
        return
    }

    addPictureToPlane(atPoint: touchPoint)
}
```

addedNodes - set with added objects. When I added translating transform with changing Z coordinate at least on 0.05 (close to the camera) detecting working good. At least before plane changing and moving ahead the node.

Comment: Please share your code - it's impossible to answer without knowing what you are doing.

Comment: Added piece of code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe what you need to do is change your `SCNHitTestSearchMode`parameter which allows you to set:

> Possible values for the searchMode option used with hit-testing
>   methods.

```
static let searchMode: SCNHitTestOption
```

Whereby:

> The value for this key is an NSNumber object containing the raw
>   integer value of an SCNHitTestSearchMode constant.

From the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnhittestsearchmode) there are three possible options you can use here:

```
case all
```

> The hit test should return all possible results, sorted from nearest
>   to farthest.

```
case any
```

> The hit test should return only the first object found, regardless of
>   distance.

```
case closest
```

> The hit test should return only the closes object found.

Based on your question therefore, you would likely need to to utilise the `all case`.

As such your `hitTest function` would probably need to look something like this (remembering that `self.augmentedRealityView` refers to an `ARSCNView`):

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    //1. Get The Current Touch Location
    guard let currentTouchLocation = touches.first?.location(in: self.augmentedRealityView) else { return }

    //2. Perform An SCNHitTest Setting The SearchMode To 1 (All) Which Returns A List Of Results Sorted From Nearest To Farthest
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {

        let hitTestResults = self.augmentedRealityView.hitTest(currentTouchLocation, options: [SCNHitTestOption.searchMode: 1])

        //3. Loop Through The Results & Get The Nodes
        for index in 0..<hitTestResults.count{

            let node = hitTestResults[index]
            print(node)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know, how I miss this parameter. Thank you very much!

Comment: Consider to change "1" with SCNHitTestSearchMode.all.rawValue to get a cleaner code